# specify jquery theme for html table

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to display a table in html page. However, the contents of the table will be loaded from a database table. I managed to do it, but the table looks like a normal html table. I would like it to look good via JQuery theme.

Is there a simple way of doing it ?

Thanks

Comment: How do you mean "look good via jQuery theme"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out this resource for styling an html table with jQuery UI:

[Style an HTML Table using jQuery UI and Theme Switcher Widget](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/08/style-html-table-using-jquery-ui-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is CSS...not jQuery.  jQuery can add some functionality to your tables like fixed headers or excel like features (re-size columns, client side sorting, etc).

But if all you are trying to do is a theme then you would do that with CSS not javascript.